# CQRS - What is the Command Dispatcher?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

To learn CQRS I'm putting together a really simple command/command handler implementation. In a lot of examples, I'm seeing the concept of a "Command Dispatcher". I'm not seeing a lot of literature on it.

I'm wondering what a Command Dispatcher is and why is it necessary? Is the Command Dispatcher and the Command Bus the same thing?

Comment: You say you've seen a lot of examples; can you link to some of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Command Dispatcher is not specifically part of CQRS; it's just an implementation detail of the Command Pattern, and an optional one at that.

A Command Dispatcher is an object that links the Action-Request with the appropriate Action-Handler.  It's purpose is to decouple the command operation from the sending and receiving objects so that neither has knowledge of the other.

A `RoutedCommand` object in WPF is a good example of a Command Dispatcher.

CQRS is a concept, not a design or implementation.  It says "Separate the responsibilities of Command from those of Querying."  Martin Fowler goes over this concept in some detail in his CQRS article; he never mentions a Command Dispatcher.

**Further Reading**
[P of EAA: CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)
[Command Query Separation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)
[Command Dispatcher](https://brightercommand.github.io/Brighter/CommandsCommandDispatcherandProcessor.html)

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an answer from my own experience.

Following the DDD approach in my *Event sourcing* projects, I encountered **a lot** of code that looked like this, for the command side of the architecture:

- identify the `Aggregate's` class for the `Command`
- load the `Aggregate` by id from the `Repository` (`Event store`)
- call a command method on the `Aggregate`, whose name looked almost like the command's name
- collect the generated `Domain events`
- persist the events to the `Repository`
- notify the subscribers about the new `Domain events`

The logical course of action was to extract this algorithm to a component whose responsibility is to send/dispatch a command to an `Aggregate`. The interface for this is like this (`PHP` code):

```
interface CommandDispatcher
{
    public function dispatchCommand(Command $command, $metadata = null);
}
```

Of course, in order to not break (too much) the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), the default implementation of this `CommandDispatcher` would use other components to fulfill its job (i.e. a `CommandSubscriber`, an `EventDispatcher` and an `AggregateRepository`).

Based on this pattern, I managed to extract a *framework* that forwards the command from the `Presentation layer` (i.e. `REST HTTP` endpoint) straight to the `Aggregate`, minimizing a lot the boiler plate code in every green field project.

By combining with the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), I also managed to implement other cross cutting concerns like authorization and logging of commands, without polluting the core domain with this kind of code.

My open source `PHP` version of the `CommandDispatcher` can be found [here](https://github.com/xprt64/cqrs-es/blob/master/src/Gica/Cqrs/Command/CommandDispatcher.php).